# Deploying azure tomcat 9.0.62 app service maps all webcontent subfolders paths to root

Tags: maven, tomcat, azure-web-app-service

When creating a tomcat app service I create subfolders in webcontent and their path is created accordingly. Example tree:

```
Webcontent:   
   index.jsp  
 folder1:
   page.jsp
```

To access page.jsp url I type: website.com/folder1/page.jsp
This all works as expected in localhost on any tomcat version, however when I deploy it to azure app service Tomcat v9.0.62 page.jsp is mapped to root: website.com/page.jsp
If I downgrade to tomcat v9.0.54 it works as expected.
I'd really appreciate any help in figuring out how to fix this behavior when deployed

Answer (score 0):

> figuring out how to fix this behavior when deployed.

Actually, it sounds like you may be encountering an issue with the default behavior of Tomcat 9.0.62 on Azure App Service.
You can add this below code in **web.xml** file:

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>Your Application Name</display-name>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextPath</param-name>
    <param-value>/your-context-path</param-value>
  </context-param>
</web-app>
```

Where JSP files located in subfolders are mapped to root directory. Replace with **context-path** of your application manually.
Refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/migration/migrate-tomcat-to-tomcat-app-service) may help you a bit.