# Why does Azure serve my static web-site in Tomcat 9.0.62 only under www.example.com/ROOT?

Tags: azure, tomcat, azure-web-app-service, http-status-code-404

I have a very simple one-page static web site stored in an Azure WebApp under `/site/wwwroot/webapps/ROOT/`

Azure supports various Tomcats

[image: Tomcats supported by Azure]

When selecting the latest version of Tomcat 9 (9.0.63, as supported by Azure at the time of writing), the website is only accessible by [www.example.com/ROOT](https://www.example.com/ROOT)

A simple downgrade to Tomcat 9.0.54 and the website is accessible at [www.example.com](https://www.example.com)

How do I get the website to work in Tomcat 9.0.63 without the `/ROOT`?

1. I tried changing adding a configuration/application setting of `SERVER_SERVLET_CONTEXT_PATH = /ROOT`
2. I tried adding

   `<context-param>`

   ```
   `<param-name>contextPath</param-name>`

   `<param-value>/ROOT</param-value>`
   ```

   `</context-param>`

to `WEB-INF/web.xml`

I also see in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75391851/deploying-azure-tomcat-9-0-62-app-service-maps-all-webcontent-subfolders-paths-t) a difference between Tomcat 9.0.54 and 9.0.62 in Azure.  I also see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1047466/unable-to-run-sample-web-application-in-azure-app) Microsoft recommending to downgrade to Tomcat 9.0.54.

Comment: Do you see anything in the logs? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @OlafKock I did not see anything significant when comparing the logs for server startup between the two Tomcats. However I edited my question significantly when I got further information.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does selecting the '(auto-update)' option choose the latest minor version automatically? And does it apply minor version updates automatically after deployment?

Comment: @Theo F. Yes to both the questions. Although it will only choose the latest Tomcat container which has been prepared by Microsoft. Indeed see https://gkgaurav31.github.io/blog/tomcat/azure_webapp/2021/03/26/detect-tomcat-version-change-on-azure-app-service-when-using-auto-update-and-more.html which discusses how to set up a notification so that the user can be notified that their configuration has been updated automatically. Since some of these containers are not so stable, I would recommend not using this option in production as one may wake up to find one's application not working.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, when deploying a web application to a Tomcat container, the context path determines the URL at which the application is accessible. If you want to access your website directly without the "/ROOT" context path

- In the java web application's `META-INF` directory, you might have a `context.xml` file (or you can create one). Add the context element with path attribute.

`<Context path="" docBase="your-webapp-name" />`

**Configuration:**

[image]

And after the deployment to the webapp. Go to the **settings>configuration>path mapping** see the virtual application and directory configure it to map the root path ("/") to your web application.

[image]

- By configuring the virtual path as `/` and mapping it to the physical path `/site/wwwroot/webapps/ROOT/`, you're telling Azure to treat the content within the `/site/wwwroot/webapps/ROOT/` directory as the content for your WebApp at the root URL. When users access your website's URL, Azure will directly serve the content from the `/site/wwwroot/webapps/ROOT/` directory without appending any additional context paths like "/ROOT".

Comment: Thank you. A few questions. (1) Is your solution two separate steps, or two alternatives. (2) In my settings/configuration/path mapping I only have the option to Mount Storage and I don't see Virtual applications and directory  (3) Do you have any idea why there is a change from Tomcat 9.0.53 to 9.0.62 with Azure?

Comment: (4) And also the META-INF/context.xml can be in the static web site and also in the WebApp.  My question was specifically about the static web site which is under ROOT. What are you suggesting I write in the content.xml?  <Context path="" docBase="ROOT" /> ?

Comment: First try to configure context.xml as shown in above if doesn't works try to set the path mappings(Virtual applications and directory) it worked for me.